# Is it possible to make a group out of unordered sets?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The property of groups that I get stuck on when attempting to define the group operation for a collection of ordered sets of integers (unordered pairs of integers) is the identity property. Namely that for some element $a$ of the group, $ae=ea=a$ for some unique $e$.

One can easily define (WLOG) $ae=a$. For example let $a=\{b,c\}$ and e=$\{1,1\}$. Then we can define $ae=\{b\cdot 1(1), c\cdot 1(1)\}=a$. This is ok to do because we are doing the $same$ change to each element of $a$, which is necessary because the set is unordered.

However, in the other direction, we would then have $ea=\{1\cdot b(c), 1\cdot b(c)\}=\{bc, bc\}\neq a$.

Since the set is unordered, I believe (correct me if Im wrong) that the same operation must be done to each element. However, this seems to prevent the commutativity of any identity element. Could we define some "uneven" identity like (1,0) and/or define the group operation in some manner to somehow satisfy the identity property of a group.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you specify what is your operation here?

Comment: My operation in my example is just $\{a,b\}\cdot \{c,d\}:=\{a\cdot c(d), b\cdot c(d)\}$ with multiplication inside the element defined as normal. However, this is just an example; I am curious IF THERE EXISTS an operation that will allow for a group made of unordered sets.

Comment: The thing is, in a set theory like ZFC, *everything* is a set. So every group is technically a group of sets. What this means is: you'll have to specify what kind of sets you're interested in. Unordered pairs of integers? Finite sets of natural numbers? All subsets of some abstract underlying group? etc.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of specification -- I'm interested in unordered pairs of integers. Will specify.

Comment: So you're asking for a group operation on the set of (unordered) pairs of integers, is that right?

Comment: Part of the problem is that, for example, $\{1,1\}=\{1\}$, so you don’t really have a pair in this notation.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, for a generic set $X$, let's set up some notation:

- $X^\vartriangle$ is the collection of two-element subsets of $X$. That is, $X^\vartriangle=\{\{a,b\}:a,b\in X;a\neq b\}$.
- $X^\blacktriangle$ is the collection of one-or-two-element subsets of $X$. That is, $X^\blacktriangle=\{\{a,b\}:a,b\in X\}$.

You might hope that if $G$ is a group then there might be a mechanical way to turn $G^\vartriangle$ or $G^\blacktriangle$ into a group. Ideally, you might want $G$ to "embed" in the larger groups, meaning $G^\vartriangle$ and/or $G^\blacktriangle$ should contain an isomorphic copy of $G$. However:

> **Bad news 1.1** Let $C_n$ be a cyclic group of order $n$, where $n$ is an even number. Then $C_n$ does not embed in either $C_n^\vartriangle$ or $C_n^\blacktriangle$.
>
> *Proof:* Just look at the orders of the groups. We have $|C_n^\vartriangle|=\binom{n}{2}=\frac12n(n-1)$, which is not a multiple of $n$ because $\frac12(n-1)$ is not an integer. So by Lagrange's theorem, if $C_n^\vartriangle$ is a group then it does not have a subgroup of order $n$. Similarly for $|C_n^\blacktriangle|=\frac12n(n+1)$.

This argument doesn't apply to the infinite cyclic group $\mathbb Z$. I'm sure you can find a group structure for $\mathbb Z^\vartriangle$ or $\mathbb Z^\blacktriangle$ that has an infinite cyclic subgroup. The sets $\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb Z^\vartriangle$, $\mathbb Z^\blacktriangle$, and $\mathbb Z^2$ have the same cardinality, so there's a lot of freedom. In the case of $\mathbb Z^\blacktriangle$, you could even bestow the diagonal with the obvious operation $\{x\}+\{y\}=\{x+y\}$. The point of **(1.1)** is that this group structure is going to have to "fold" the rest of the set into some messed-up shape that doesn't respect modular arithmetic.